# Bootstrap: any systematic, established way of changing default settings?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Just dicovered Bootstrap. I noticed that changing default styles requires research. For example right now, I want to change the default colour of buttons' background colour. How can I know the proper way to apply this kind of change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways of doing it depending on how you choose to build your website.

**If you are directly including bootstrap files:**

You have to override the css declaration of each and every style that you wish to change.  Tedious but works.

**Customize bootstrap in bootstrap's customization page**
Bootstrap 3 gives a customization page where you can customize the less variables and download it.  http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

**If you are using less/scss version of bootstrap**
You can just override/change the variables declaration.

I generally prefer the thrid way of customizing bootstrap. I use sass version of bootstrap available as ruby gems and override the variable declarations.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply change the [variables.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less) file which is provided by `Twitter Bootstrap`. Then, you can use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) to compile it into `.css` file.

As you mentioned above, `you want to change the default colour of buttons' background colour`. We can simply change the variable's value:

```
// Buttons
// -------------------------

@btn-font-weight:                normal;

@btn-default-color:              #333;
@btn-default-bg:                 #fff;
@btn-default-border:             #ccc;
```

Comment: Also, the Bootstrap website has a nifty [customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) that can make generating custom LESS files easier.